# Ashkenazi hoshanot schedule when first day Sukkot is Monday

Tags: tefilla, sukkot, hoshanos

When the first day of *sukkot* is a Monday, the following is the standard Ashkenazi *hoshanot* schedule for the first six days (found in all *siddurim*/*machzorim* that I've seen and e.g. in Levush [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14585&st=&pgnum=250)):

1. *Lema'an amitach*
2. *Even shetiyah*
3. *E'eroch shu'i*
4. *Om ani chomah*
5. *E-l lemoshao't*
6. *Om netzurah*

I understand that 1. and 2. are said as early as possible, and 3. is said on the first available day of *chol hamoed* (consistent with every other year (see e.g. Levushei S'rad [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32863&st=&pgnum=134))). I understand that on *shabbat* the relevant *hoshana* (6. *om netzurah*) is recited (consistent with every other year).

My question is about the relative postions of 4. and 5. Why does *om ani chomah* precede *e-l lemosha'ot*?

I understand that in such a year, *adon hamoshia* cannot be recited, as it is only ever recited on the sixth day of *sukkot*, which in this case is *shabbat*.

But why is its substitute *om ani chomah* (which is only ever customarily recited in a year of this type, notwithstanding Eliyah Rabbah [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7767&st=&pgnum=424)) recited before *e-l lemosha’ot*? Why not recite it afterwards, in the same way that every other year *adon hamoshia* is after *e-l lemosha’ot*?

[It's possible that there's some reason that would specifically link *om ani chomah* to the fourth day of *sukkot* and *e-l lemosha'ot* to the fifth day, but that seems somewhat unlikely when we consider a year where the first day of *sukkot* is a Tuesday, in which case common practice is to recite *e-l lemosha'ot* on the fourth day of *sukkot* and not recite *om ani chomah* at all.]

**In summary, please explain why *om ani chomah* comes before *e-l lemosha’ot*.**

Comment: I recall that one of the Hoshannot must be said specifically a week after Yom Kippur. It may be the one you mentioned, and that may affect the ordering, here. I'll see if I can locate my Art Scroll Hoshanot book at home. "Bug" me if you don't get an answer in the next few days.

Comment: I believe you are referring to e’eroch shu’i which is always recited one week after Yom Kippur (unless it’s shabbat). I’m not sure that that’s going to help understand what’s going on here though...

Comment: Perhaps el lemoshaot has precedence over om ani choma because EL isn't recited on hoshana raba while OAC is. Some support perhaps from AhS https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%92#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%92_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%90 that we specifically use hosanot that won't be recited later.

Comment: Not all Ashkenazi communities use the same hosha'not in the same order (see Goldschmidt). Rheinland communities historically said E'eroch Shu'i on the first day, unless Om Netzurah were recited instead

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing too deep. E-l lemoshaot was instituted for the fifth day of Sukkot, as it is practical to be said then almost every year. Om ani Choma is an extra, said only out of necessity in a year like this one. It is therefore said on the fourth day, which for other technical reasons doesn't have any fixed nusach.

Comment: "consider a year where the first day of sukkot is a Tuesday, in which case common practice is to recite e-l lemosha'ot on the fourth day of sukkot"

Comment: When the first day is a Tuesday e-l lemosha'ot cannot be said on the fifth day as it is Shabbat. It is therefore brought forward a day (as mentioned, the fourth day doesn't have a fixed nusach).

Comment: Why is it brought forward a day if it is instituted for the fifth day? Just say Om Ani Chomah on the fourth day that year too!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya tcdw. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Double AA- E-l lemoshaot is considered 'more critical' than om ani choma, thus it is said every year (if possible on day five, if not on day four).

Comment: @tcdw why is it more critical? how do you know it is more critical?

Comment: I don't know why it is more critical. I know it is more critical because it is said every year, unlike om ani choma which is only said (apart from Hoshana Raba) when the first day is on a Monday.